# High performance (python) library for reading tiff files?

Tags: python, tiff

I am using code to read a .tiff file in order to calculate a fractal dimension. My code looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

raster = plt.imread('xyz.tif')

for i in range(x1, x2):
    for j in range(y1, y2):
        pixel = raster[i][j]
```

This works, but I have to read a lot of pixels so I would like this to be fast, and ideally minimize electricity usage given current events. Is there a better library than matplotlib for this purpose? For example, could using a library specialized for matrix operations such as pandas help? Additionally, would another language such as C have better performance than python?

Comment: You need to benchmark/profile your code before worrying about finding a faster TIFF reader, because I would bet that the double `for` loops take significantly longer to run than reading the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: @cgohlke in the comments and others have found that cv2 is slower than tifffile for large and/or compressed images. It is best you test the different options on realistic data for your application.

I have found `cv2` to be the fastest library for this. Using 5000 128x128 uint16 tif images gives the following result:

```
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t0 = time.time()
for file in files:
    raster = plt.imread(file)
print(f'{time.time()-t0:.2f} s')
```

1.52 s

```
import time
from PIL import Image
t0 = time.time()
for file in files:
    im = np.array(Image.open(file))
print(f'{time.time()-t0:.2f} s')
```

1.42 s

```
import time
import tifffile
t0 = time.time()
for file in files:
    im = tifffile.imread(file)
print(f'{time.time()-t0:.2f} s')
```

1.25 s

```
import time
import cv2
t0 = time.time()
for file in files:
    im = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
print(f'{time.time()-t0:.2f} s')
```

0.20 s

`cv2` is a computer vision library written in c++, which as the other commenter mentioned is much faster than pure python. Note the `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` flag, otherwise `cv2` will convert monochrome images to 8-bit rgb.

Comment: Are these uncompressed TIFF? I can't reproduce these timings. cv2 is not 3 times faster than tifffile or PIL on my system. The test images are rather small and Python overhead is large. For larger images, e.g. 1280x1280, cv2 times the worst on my system. The [imagecodecs](https://pypi.org/project/imagecodecs/) library is faster than cv2 and handles more data types.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure which library is the fastest but I have very good experience with Pillow:

```
from PIL import Image
raster = Image.open('xyz.tif')
```

then you could convert it to a numpy array:

```
import numpy
pixels = numpy.array(raster)
```

I would need to see the rest of the code to be able to recommend any other libraries. As for the language C++ or C would have better performance as they are low level languages. So depends on how complex your operations are and how much data you need to process, C++ scripts were shown to be 10-200x faster(increasing with the complexity of calculations). Hope this helps if you have any further questions just ask.